# Counting each alphabet character in an array of Strings Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of Strings. 
(Each string is only one character, but in order to use the scanner, I had to make it an array of strings, because there's no input.nextchar.) 
I want to find out how many of each letter in the alphabet there are in the array, and then create if statements based on which letter there are the most of.
How do I do this?
I am a beginner so please explain in the simplest way you can. 
Thank you so much to anyone who can help!

Comment: You can use [`String#toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) or [`String#charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) to get the characters from a `String`. Then use [`Character#isAlphabetic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic-int-)

Comment: If you have absolutely no idea where to start, please have a look at Patricia Shanahan's excellent page as it will give you some ideas: [Starting Writing a Program](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html), the key process being to break the big project down into small steps, and then solving each small step one at a time. If you're still having problems, then you might wish to consider talking to your instructor or showing us what you've done and asking a **much** more specific question or set of questions. Much luck!

Comment: Before designing your algorithm, analyze the problem a bit more. An alphabet is usually a subset of letters used in a writing system and letters aren't the only characters in the writing system. Also, letters often have uppercase and lowercase forms. Will these issues apply to your input?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) where the key is the letter and the value is the number of occurrences. For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> letterCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String letter : letters) { //letters is your array of strings
    if (letterCount.containsKey(letter)) {
        letterCount.put(letter, letterCount.get(letter) + 1);
    } else {
        letterCount.put(letter, 1);
    }
}
```

Now you can check how many times a specific letter shows up like this:

```
int numberOfEs = letterCount.get("E");
```

You can also loop through all the letters by calling `letterCount.keySet()` to see which one is the most frequent.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hashmap for each character as its key and count as its value. (Default 0 as value).
Iterate over your array of string, get each character from hashmap, increment count and set it back.

So end of the iteration, you'll have all count for alphabet characters.

Then proceed thru your further coding.

If required, then sort hashmap based on values too.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do might be best accomplished by using a char array instead.

So ASCII characters 65 - 90 represent the characters A-Z.

Casting it to an int will give you the ASCII value of it I believe. 
You'll need an int array to hold 26 ints. Loop through your array, convert each int into it's ASCII value and increment the index of that array. I haven't tried it out, but I don't see why it would't work.

In the end you'll be able to work out how many of each letter has appeared.

Also, I doubt introducing him to Collections would be a good idea since he is a beginner.

Comment: A Java char is a UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint. The UTF-16 encoding of each of Unicode's Basic Latin Letters (A-Z and a-z) is one code unit. So, your algorithm would work if the input is all Basic Latin Letters in the same case.